# response detail error:2,errMsg:post method api body check failed! Agora REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, agora.io

```
const Authorization = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${config.CUSTOMERID}:${config.CUSTOMER_SECRET}`).toString("base64")}`;
const acquire = await axios.post(`https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${config.agoraAppId}/cloud_recording/acquire`,{
                          cname: groupId,
                          uid: userId,
                          clientRequest: {
                          },
                        },
                        { headers: { Authorization } }
                      );
```

Getting the following response when i call agora live streaming cloud recording from nodejs code using axios.

```
{
 code: 2,
 reason: 'response detail error:2,errMsg:post method api body check failed!'
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but both cname and uid are defined. Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you have been successfully Authorized but you are passing either wrong value or it is not defined in your body or URL.
Please check if any variable you are passing is undefined or contains wrong/incomplete value.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the header as an object with they Authorization key, in your case:

```
{
   headers: {'Authorization': "Basic " + Authorization}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass `cname` and `uid` as string - this was my case